# How to make a simultaneously insert in table and pass the same value

Tags: c#, sql, blazor

I intend to insert into two different tables. Tables: Test and Test1. When creating I want to enter the test table id in the Test1 table. But the id is PK from the Test table.

For example:
Table Material: I insert (ID: PK, name:xpto)

I want create in simultaneously and pass this ID to other table, in this case Material_C

Table Material_C: (ID: PK, idMaterial: (???))

How can i make it in C# ?

Comment: nothing related to blazor?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322601/sql-insert-into-related-tables | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074430/insert-data-into-3-related-tables

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you want to handle it, there are different ways to achieve it.

One of the ways is using a database trigger.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trg_InsertToMaterial_C
ON dbo.Material
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Material_C([ID], Name) VALUES (INSERTED.ID, INSERTED.Name)
END
```

The trick here is to utilize `INSERTED` keyword in the body, this gives you access to what you already have inserted. With that you can automate another insert to your target table, with whatever values you like.